# Best solution for 2 ruby's on a production server (nginx, passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger, rbenv

I have two rails-apps running with rails 4.2 and ruby 2.3.
Now I need to install one legacy app with rails 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3
Some code of this app is not working with ruby 2.3

Tried to create gemsets and rubies for newer ones, bundle installed in their gemsets and they crash.

Tried to only install a ruby and gemset for the old one: rvm --create --ruby-version ruby-1.9.3-p551@trendguide_gemset inside the directory, bundled and also the new one crashed.

Passenger gets irritated? What is a easy solution, perhaps without rvm?
Found this: 
http://blog.arkency.com/2012/11/one-app-one-user-one-ruby/

But this is unclear to me..
Any advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)
It is sure way not to mess up things with different versions of gems-rubies, but need some introduction